# Converting seconds to minutes and hours in youtubedl

Tags: python, time, duration, youtube-dl

```
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=self.title, description=f"**Channel:** {self.uploader}\n **Duration:** {self.duration}", url=self.video_url)
        embed.set_footer(
            text=f"Requested by: {self.requested_by.name}",
            icon_url=self.requested_by.avatar_url)
        if self.thumbnail:
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.thumbnail)
        return embed
```

So it is all about the second line. Right now the output is shown the duration in seconds. I would like to change the format so that the actual time is displayed. For example the video is 3 min long:

- On YouTube 03:00 is shown. My bot converts it to 300 seconds.
  Is there a way to change this so the actual time is given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going from the docs (https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme), `duration` is the `Length of the video in seconds`, so you can just manually go from seconds `hours:minutes:seconds`.

```
total_seconds = self.duration
hours = (total_seconds - ( total_seconds % 3600))/3600
seconds_minus_hours = (total_seconds - hours*3600)
minutes = (seconds_minus_hours - (seconds_minus_hours % 60) )/60
seconds = seconds_minus_hours - minutes*60

time = '{}:{}:{}'.format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))
```

that time string may be a little messy (the `int()` is so when you print it it doesn't have decimal points) but that has all the relevant info.

Comment: Thanks to you, that worked perfectly. My only question now would be:
Will the removal of ' ' affect the code as it is also outputted. Second questions: Now the duration is shown like this: '0.0:3.0:46.0' - Is there a way to remove the not needed numbers/dots so that only: 00:03:46 or 3:46 is shown?

Comment: yes. the brackets in the time string store what is put in the `.format()` function. You can change that string around to do something like `'{}:{}{}'`.format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))`. the `int()` should get rid of the decimal points (because the variables are stored as floats).

Comment: time = '{}:{}:{}'.format(int(hours), str(minutes/10).replace('.', ''), int(seconds))

Answer (score 0):

For those who are passing by and still need help, here is a EASIER way to convert i've done.

```
time_to_convert = 249 #YOUR VARIABLE

s= time_to_convert % 60  #seconds
m= time_to_convert / 60 #minutes

print(f'{int(m)}min{s:02d}s')   #":02d" will let your seconds look like this 05s

#       ^int() maybe you don't need this at all
```

for the HOUR your just need to divide the seconds by the TOTAL of SECONDS that 1 hour has. Meaning => 3600

```
h = time_to_convert / 3600 #total ammount of s in a hour
print(f'{int(h)}')  #now you'll need the int() unless you want to show broken/floating hours
```